# Can an already downloaded malicious file detect the operating system?

Tags: malware, drive-by-download

A similar question has been asked here:

[Can hackers detect my operating system?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48511/can-hackers-detect-my-operating-system)

My question is, if malicious file has been downloaded off of a secure 3rd party website (i.e. not owned/controlled by the malware writer), would this malware be able to detect which operating system it has been downloaded to? Or would the malware need to be tailored to one particular OS?

Comment: I think your real question is: "can a binary determine what OS launched it?" And the answer is "it depends on the binary". An exe is only going to execute on Windows. A  python/Javascript/macro language malware can determine the OS. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Thanks. My follow up question is, if someone were to create a file that jailbreaks whichever device it ends up on, is this possible? Jailbreaking, as far as I know, requires a low-level language.

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on how jailbreaking works on the device.